# What is the probability that a subsequence converges?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

I was wondering: let be $r_n$ a sequence of numbers randomly (i.d.d.) chosen from $[0, 1]$ so $r_n \in [0, 1]-\{r_1, r_2, ... ,r_{n-1}\}$. And any r is a real number. Is we call $s(r_n)$ the space of all subsequences of $r_n$... What is the probability of pick a convergent subsequence from $s(r_n)$?

My intuition says that the probability is $0$, but I can't imagine any demonstration. Can you help me, please?

Many thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: Does it change in any way the outcome of this problem if we choose all $r_n$ to be **rational numbers**?

Comment: It is worth pointing out that despite $r_n$ being taken from $[0,1]-\{r_1,r_2,\dots,r_{n-1}\}$, we only removed finitely many choices and there are uncountably infinitely many choices still remaining, so it has essentially no effect.

Comment: Changing it to be rational numbers, it still doesn't affect anything since we still have infinitely many choices for each $r_n$ and only finitely many invalid choices.  Note further that rational numbers are dense.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Changing it to rationals does make a difference, since now you really do have to specify the probability of each rational, and they cannot all be zero (there's no uniform distribution on the rationals).  In fact, assuming you assign positive probability to each rational, then with probability 1, every rational will be repeated infinitely many times in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed 0. This can be shown in the following way:

For the chosen sequence to be convergent, there must be a point in the sequence where all points are within an $\epsilon$ boundary of the limit of the sequence. As such, let's take $\epsilon=\frac14$. In this case, the probability of each element of the sequence after this point being within $\frac14$ of the limit is at most $\frac12$. So, as we pick more and more terms of the sequence, the probability of all of them being within some range goes down to 0

Comment: So the measure of the subset of **all** convergent subsequences is 0?

Comment: @CarlosToscano-Ochoa: That is correct.  In fact, with probability one, your sequence is dense in [0,1], which is about as far from "convergent" as you can get.